# Functions and Procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between a Function and a Procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: Isn't this something you can find in documentation? I am trying to understand the reason for you to ask this question.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid and unambiguous question. As far as I know SO is not just for things you can't find in documentation, so...

Answer (score 1):

You can embed functions in SQL statements just like you would any native SQL funcion like COALESCE, CONVERT, etc.  Procs can return a value, but the values that an be returned are limited.  For example, if I recall correctly, you can return a table variable from a function, but not a stored proc.

**So with a function, you can do things like this:**

```
SELECT dbo.MyFunc(myColumn) as [Column Alias Name] FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTableVariableReturningFunc() as tbl
```

**With stored procs, you can get the return value like so:**

```
DELCARE @ReturnVal as int

EXEC @ReturnVal = USP_MyStoredProc
```

Answer (score 1):

Another diffrence is that user defined functions can't modify database data, while procedures can.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, to me, a function would be used to perform *common* tasks across the entire database in any query.  A stored procedure on the other hand would be something I would use to perform complex tasks done on a regular basis but aren't common.  For example, the stored procedures I typically write will grab data from a file and upload to a table (whilst performing many other operations in the process such as auditing etc.).  It's not something that would be used anywhere else, but I would run it once a day.